# Perl threads reading input lines

Tags: perl

I am so confused with threads! I hope someone here can help.

The following is my code:

```
$LOGFILE = "log.txt";
open(LOGFILE) or die("Could not open log file.");
foreach $line (<LOGFILE>) {
    chomp($line);    



 my $number = shift;


 system("echo $number total lines > count");
  print "This thread is printing the number  $number\n";
  sleep(1);
```

`log.txt`:

Comment: [The use of interpreter-based threads in perl is officially discouraged.](https://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html)

Comment: You forgot to state your question ... ?

Comment: @Matt Jacob, ...if you want lightweight threads. Perfectly fine otherwise.

Comment: @andrew99, Three things you need to fix first: 1) Your code doesn't even compile. 2) ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`. 3) You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: What is your problem with this code?

Comment: @ikegami I'm always glad when you write that. The [warning](https://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html#WARNING) Matt refers to also says _“Few people know how to use them correctly or will be able to provide help.”_ I have a script that makes heavy use of threads and Queues. It works like a charm and if threads would disappear from Perl, that would be a real pain for me.

Comment: @PerlDuck, Indeed. They are by no means deprecated. Someone just felt like saying "you're too dumb to use threads" as the official position, and is poisoning the community.

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );
use threads;

use Thread::Queue qw( );   # 3.01+

use constant NUM_WORKERS => 10;

sub worker {
   my ($job) = @_;
   print("This is log $job\n");
}

{
   my $log_qfn = "log.txt";
   open(my $log_fh, '<', $log_qfn)
      or die("Can't open \"$log_qfn\": $!\n");

   my $q = Thread::Queue->new();
   for (1..NUM_WORKERS) {
      async {
         while (defined( my $job = $q->dequeue() )) {
            worker($job);
         }
      };
   }

   while (my $line = <$log_fh>) {
      chomp($line);
      $q->enqueue($line);
   }

   $q->end();

   $_->join() for threads->list();
}
```

Of course, the output won't necessarily be in the same order. If you need that, it's going to take a whole lot of extra work.

Comment: Thanks sir!but it doesnt work ,when i print it! while (my $line = <$log_fh>) {
      chomp($line);
            print "$line\n"

Comment: I need the output printed

Comment: i dont know,u know im newbie brothers ;(

Comment: Haha,u forgot to to put the module!anyway thnk brother!respect

Answer (score 0):

First off - there's a bunch of problems with your code even before we get to threading. Because parallel code introduces a whole world of new bugs, it's REALLY IMPORTANT to have decent code to start off with.

Yours doesn't even compile, or work single threaded.

- `LOGFILE` and `$LOGFILE` aren't the same thing.
- don't use `foreach` read a filehandle - use `while`.
- You don't actually pass any file data anywhere
- You maintain an `@threads` array which you don't use - mostly this isn't needed, because you have `threads->list`.
- Turn on `use strict` and `use warnings;` - threads are messy and create whole new classes of bugs and intermittent faults. Your code must be bullet proof before introducing the additional complexity.

There's a fundamental point you're missing here - threads are non deterministic. The whole point is - you no longer have a defined execution sequence, and so you *cannot* rely on any particular output ordering.

Also - threading is official discouraged *because* it's misunderstood - perl threads are not lightweight, so spawning lots of them is horribly inefficient. If you want to go down that road, then `Parallel::ForkManager` is probably the tool for the job.

And even leaving that aside - they parallelise compute resources, not disk IO. If you're "just" reading a file, then you won't make it go faster than the disk controller, which is your limiting factor.

Anyway, to do your thing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use Thread::Queue qw ( ); 

my $num_threads = 10; 

my $work_q = Thread::Queue -> new;
my $output_q = Thread::Queue -> new; 

sub worker {
   my $count = 0; 
   print "Worker: ", threads -> self -> tid, " started and waiting for input\n";
   while ( my $item = $work_q -> dequeue ) { 
      $output_q -> enqueue ( threads -> self -> tid. ": ". $count++. " items: $item");
       print "Processing: $item";
   }
   print "Worker: ", threads -> self -> tid, " exiting\n";
}

sub serialise_output {

   print "Serialiser waiting for things to print: ", threads -> self -> tid,"\n";
   while ( my $output_item = $output_q -> dequeue ) { 
     print $output_item,"\n";
   }
}

my @workers = map { threads -> create ( \&worker ) } 1..$num_threads; 
my $serialiser = threads -> create ( \&serialise_output ); 


open ( my $input, '<', 'log.txt' ) or die $!;
while ( my $line = <$input> ) {
  chomp ( $line ) ;
  $work_q -> enqueue ( $line ); 
}
close ( $input );

$work_q -> end; #tell the threads that's all of it, so they exit. 
$_ -> join for @workers; #wait for all the workers to exit. 

$output_q -> end; #need to wait for workers to finish, so we don't create race condition. 
$serialiser -> join;


print "All threads done\n";
```

Note - the serialiser gets it's input in a fairly random order, based on which thread processed which line. You can either stream that straight to an open file handle (don't try and open the same file in multiple threads - that'll get ugly) or do some sort of sorting and coalescing before printing.

You absolutely cannot rely on any sort of ordering of your file io, because you're dividing up work - that's rather the point. But you don't need a separate thread to serialise output if you're going to wait until you have all of it (e.g. if you're going to sort it) - you can just do that in the 'main' thread instead.

Comment: Re "*`LOGFILE` and `$LOGFILE` aren't the same thing.*", That code was actually correct (or as correct as 1-arg `open` can be). `open(LOGFILE)` opens the file named by package var `$LOGFILE`.